# Laravel - Disable Updated At when updating

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

Get a problem with update using query builder on laravel 5. I've tried to disabled the updated_at but keep failing.

Here is my code:

```
    $query = StockLog::where('stock_id', $id)->whereBetween('created_at', $from, $to])->update(['batch_id' => $max + 1]);
```

I've tried 2 ways:
first one at my model i set:

```
public function setUpdatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    /*do nothing*/
}
```

Second one:

```
$stocklog = new StockLog;
$stocklog->timestamps = false;

$query = $stocklog::where('stock_id', $id)->whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])->update([
        'batch_id' => $max + 1]);
```

both of them are failed. is there anyway to disabled the updated_at?

Thanks in advance

Comment: As in permanently turn it off? Or just for one specific query?

Comment: Hi. Permanent off. @TheShiftExchange

Comment: And when you say "both of them are failed" - what is the actual fail/error?

Comment: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' @TheShiftExchange

Comment: If you dont want to have it at all then its better to not have it in your migration. If you are using migrations you probably have something like ````$table->timestamps();````  What you could do is set this ````public $timestamps = false;```` in your model and ad the created_at manualy

Comment: @sstarlight You can disable it in model, check my answer.

Comment: @sstarlight laravel always expects the updated_at and created_at unless you have told it that it does not exists

Comment: @vps i've tried. i comment your answer. THanks

Comment: @Szenis Yes. i've tried to disabled it. but no luck. any suggestion?

Comment: ````public function up()
        {
                Schema::create('password_resets', function(Blueprint $table)
                {
                        $table->string('email')->index();
                        $table->string('token')->index();
                        $table->timestamp('created_at');
                });
        }````  This is how my password reset migration looks it does not have any updated_at field. Could you show your migration?

Comment: My table not using any migrations.

Comment: @sstarlight Oh yea then my suggestion is not going to help you :(

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> By default, Eloquent will maintain the created_at and updated_at columns on your database table automatically. Simply add these timestamp columns to your table and Eloquent will take care of the rest.

I don't really suggest removing them. But if you want use the following way.

add the following to your **model**:

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

This will disable the timestamps.

**EDIT**: it looks like you want to keep the `created_at` field, you can override the `getUpdatedAtColumn` in your model.

Use the following code:

```
public function getUpdatedAtColumn() {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: i need the created at for other query.

Comment: ouch!! it's success~. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 12):

In your model, add this method:

```
/**
 * @param  mixed  $value
 * @return $this
 */
public function setUpdatedAt($value)
{
    return $this;
}
```

**UPDATE: In Laravel 5.5**:

Just try to use this in your model:

```
const CREATED_AT = null;
const UPDATED_AT = null;
```

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, but led me in the right direction to this solution that did:

```
class Whatever extends Model {
    //...
    const UPDATED_AT=NULL;
    //...
```

*Laravel 5.3*

Comment: I believe this is the best answer to the question. from the source: `if (! is_null(static::UPDATED_AT) && ...) { $this->setUpdatedAt($time); }`

Comment: @andonovn Thanks! And thanks for providing the source that backs it up

Answer (score 5):

In this case it's better to use ***Query Builder*** instead of ***Eloquent*** because ***Query Builder*** doesn't implicitely edits timestamps fields. The use of ***Query Builder*** will have the advantage of targetting only the concerned update operation without alterate all your model.

In one line you could do:

```
$query = \DB::table('stocklogs')->where('stock_id', $id)->whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])->update(['batch_id' => $max + 1]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use following if you want make it off permanently.

Add following to your model...

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

And if you want to keep using created_at, then add following.

```
    static::creating( function ($model) {
        $model->setCreatedAt($model->freshTimestamp());
    });
```

OR use following way...

```
/**
 * Set the value of the "updated at" attribute.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $value
 * @return void
 */
public function setUpdatedAt($value)
{
    $this->{static::UPDATED_AT} = $value;
}
```

Comment: I've tried first one and the second one.

for the first it gives me a lot of red syntax. especially on static::creating
second one not working. it still try to update 'updated_at'

Comment: Check this http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#timestamps  there is a way to block timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

Before updating you need to add **->toBase()**

For example

```
Model::query()->where([...])->toBase()->update([...]);
```

in your case it will be

```
StockLog::where('stock_id', $id)->whereBetween('created_at', $from, $to])->toBase()->update(['batch_id' => $max + 1]);
```